# To convert all the class properties to IDictionary<string, dynamic>

Tags: c#, hash-map, reflection

I have the requirement to return the result of my ViewModel as a Dictionary of KeyValue pairs. My view model comprises of multiple classes and can have null values in properties. I need to return only values which are not null and non-zero in case of `double/string` types. Following is the class I created:

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
    {
        public static IDictionary<string, dynamic> ConvertToDictionary(this object source, BindingFlags bindingAttribute = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public)
        {
            IDictionary<string, dynamic> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();

            PropertyInfo[] properties = source.GetType().GetProperties(bindingAttribute);
            foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in properties)
            {
                if (propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(System.String) ||
                    propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(System.Int16) ||
                    propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(System.Int32) ||
                    propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(System.Int64) ||
                    propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(System.Double) ||
                    propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(System.Decimal) ||
                    propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(System.Guid)
                )
                {
                    dynamic propertyValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(source, null);
                    if (propertyValue != null)
                    {
                        if (propertyValue.GetType() == typeof(double))
                        {
                            propertyValue = Math.Round(propertyValue, 4);
                        }

                        dictionary.Add(propertyInfo.Name, propertyValue);
                    }
                }
                else if (propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsGenericType)
                {
                    dynamic propertyValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(source, null);
                    if (propertyValue != null)
                    {
                        if (propertyValue.GetType() == typeof(double))
                        {
                            propertyValue = Math.Round(propertyValue, 4);
                        }

                        dictionary.Add(propertyInfo.Name, propertyValue);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    dynamic complexPropertyValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(source, null);
                    if (complexPropertyValue != null)
                    {
                        PropertyInfo[] complexProperties = complexPropertyValue.GetType().GetProperties();
                        foreach (PropertyInfo complexPropertyInfo in complexProperties)
                        {
                            dynamic propertyValue = complexPropertyInfo.GetValue(complexPropertyValue, null);
                            if (propertyValue != null)
                            {
                                if (propertyValue.GetType() == typeof(double))
                                {
                                    propertyValue = Math.Round(propertyValue, 4);
                                }

                                dictionary.Add(complexPropertyInfo.Name, propertyValue);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            FormatDictionary(dictionary);
            return dictionary;
        }

        private static IDictionary<string, dynamic> FormatDictionary(IDictionary<string, dynamic> source)
        {
            foreach (var item in source)
            {
                if (item.Value.GetType() == typeof(int) || item.Value.GetType() == typeof(double))
                {
                    if (item.Value == 0)
                    {
                        source.Remove(item);
                    }
                }

                if (item.Value.GetType() == typeof(string))
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.Value))
                    {
                        source.Remove(item);
                    }
                }
            }
            return source;
        }
    }
```

Is it the right approach. Any feedback will be appreciated.

Comment: Right approach compared to  ?

Comment: For using two `foreach loops` to check for nested properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my feedback

1. Why do you use full types name, like `System.Double` ? I prefer shorter version , just `double`.
2. Also I prefer to use `var` as it makes code shorter and more readable. So instead of `IDictionary<string, dynamic> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();` I would use `var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();` which looks neater for me.
3. For some reason you do not handle `float` datatype ... Probaly you just missed it. The same for `char` and `boolean` datatypes. So your code will fail for class with these properties types.
4. That is also strange that you `Round` only `double` values. What about `float` and `decimal` types ? probably you should be consistent.
5. Looks like in first `if` statement you wanted to check if type is built-in primitive type. I would recommend extract separate method for it - `IsPrimitiveType(Type type)`
6. Function name `FormatDictionary` is misleading as for me. Because it does not format a dictionary, but filter it. So, I think `FilterDictionary` is a better name
7. It is considered as bad practice to modify input parameter inside function, but `FormatDictionary` does it. I would recommend to create new collection and return it, instead of modifying existed one

That is what I see on the first glance. Probably there is something else if look closer :)

Comment: BTW: ["As a matter of style, use of the keyword is favoured over use of the complete system type name."](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm). So use `int` instead of `Int32` etc.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Appreciated.